# How to change pixels in a bounding box within and image to black?

Tags: python, image-processing, mask

I have a set of binary masks that contain some noise (image below). I want to write a piece of code to change the pixels from the areas that contain that noise to black. I have tried with the code below but this does not change any pixel from the original array to pitch black. Does anyone know how I can do this?

[Mask with noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MC3o.png)

I have tried the following code:

```
ht, wt = array.shape
area = ht * wt
for region in sme.regionprops(array):
    if 0.1 > (region.area/area) > 0.001:
        x1 = math.ceil(region.bbox[0])
        x2 = math.ceil(region.bbox[1])
        y1 = math.ceil(region.bbox[2])
        y2 = math.ceil(region.bbox[3])
        for item in array[y1:y2, x1:x2]:
            array = np.where(array, item>0.1, 0)
            plt.imshow(array, cmap='gray')
            plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post a [mre].

Comment: It's not clear, to me at least, what you want to do. Please show your starting images and at least a mock-up of the expected result. Thank you.